# Is it fine to use href and onclick together in single anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, seo, anchor

We are having issues on certain web pages for mozilla browser in android where new link is not opened if placed as href but working fine when placed inside onclick.

```
<a target="_blank" href='http://www.google.com'>Not working in mozilla firefox in android device</a>

<a onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');">Working in mozilla firefox in android device but SEO?</a>
```

But we are still not sure if 2nd would be crawled by SEO bots due to javascript dependency. So, I have used onclick for opening and firefox and href for bots i.e.

```
<a target="_blank" href='http://www.google.com' onclick="return window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');">Working in mozilla firefox in android device and can be crawled by JS disabled bots</a>
```

Is it fine to put href for bots AND onclick for such exceptional cases OR there is some issue in this approach?

Comment: onclick has the disadvantage that it couldn't used as link in the browser context menu (e.g. open in new tab/window option)

Comment: but it is getting opened in new window as demonstrated in code

Comment: A better solution is to try and fix the actual issue; you mention "certain" web pages; does that mean it works on some and not on others? It sure sounds like something is buggy on your end, not Firefox's.

Comment: @ChrisG: I agree. But I can't figure out a way.

Comment: @ChrisG: do you have android device with mozilla installed, if yes, i could share URL where you can test that bug?

Comment: You may have blocked popups, double check everything, there is nothing wrong with the code

Comment: @maverick I indeed have an Android device with Firefox installed, send along the URL and I will check

Comment: @ChrisG: Check https://staging.carwale.com:9006/m/used/ This is faulty link. If you open "TestLink href" link on android firefox, it would open blank new tab instead of opening google as expected. While you  Check https://staging.carwale.com:9006/ViewPage1.cshtml This has correct behavior and is opening both links in new window as expected. The most surprising part is both have exact same anchor links. I suspect there is some other script here that is causing this

Comment: @ChrisG: I have also posted question for the same query https://stackoverflow.com/q/47238286/5285062

Comment: I can confirm this opens a new `about:blank` tab on my mobile. I don't know the cause, but it has to be one of the scripts. I'd store the generated faulty HTML as new test document, then remove one script after the other until it works.

Comment: @ChrisG: Yeah, that has to be the way. I am trying that. Will post once its solved.

Comment: @ChrisG: There's something really surprising. It is due to some GTM script but i can't find the reason. I have put code with GTM script view-source:https://staging.carwale.com:9006/m/used/default1.aspx Here "test link href" is not getting opened in new window for android firefox. Whereas view-source:https://staging.carwale.com:9006/m/used/default.aspx doesn't have GTM and it works fine

Comment: @ChrisG: The unbelievable part is that I have another page with same code with GTM script at other location i..e here https://staging.carwale.com:9006/default.cshtml and it works perfectly fine in android mozila

Comment: I have posted new question with detailed explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47249764/android-device-firefox-browsers-gtm-script-not-allowing-anchor-tag-link-to-be-o

Comment: @ChrisG: Any opinion here? Can I use window.open and href together here to avoid this? I need to make sure that it has no SEO implications

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming. SEO questions may be asked on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Machavity It's not really about SEO; while the current workaround might interfere with SEO, the actual question is why a basic link doesn't work in Firefox on Android.

Comment: @ChrisG `Is it fine to put href for bots` Looks like an SEO question to me.

Comment: @Machavity Like I said, the current workaround for the actual problem will likely interfere with SEO, but that's a separate issue. Read the question and the comments and it will become clear that this is not, in any meaningful way, "an SEO question".

Answer (score 2):

In general those are completely different although they may achieve the same goal. `onclick` calls javascript but `href` doesn't.

Putting them together to achieve the same goal is first a bad convention and second unnecessary use of javascript.

The href attribute of the anchor tag is for static site linking, for example a link to a youtube video or something. Javascript though is more powerful and can generate dynamic links with the onclick attribute, so it's up to you how you are willing to use the redirection logic. For your example, using both is **NOT** ok, so use this

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Click me</a>
```